# exec `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` show `Error connecting to agent: Bad address`

Tags: windows, git, ssh, git-bash

I want to config `ssh` to `github` refer to [github help](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/), but when I run `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` after `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`, it shows:

> Error connecting to agent: Bad address.

My system is `windows` 10, and My git version is `git version 2.7.2.windows.1`. I use `git` bash to execute these command line.

1. $ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
   `Agent pid 8292`
2. $ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

   > Error connecting to agent: Bad address

Anyone who can help me, thanks in advance

Comment: where did you install ssh from? What version?

Comment: I use ssh tool integrated in git, the version is `OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015`